# DateTimeParseException - could not be parsed at index 15

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin

I get this exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02/16/21 09:11 PM'
> could not be parsed at index 15

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    private fun extractTimestamp(date: String, time: String): Long {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a")
        return LocalDateTime.parse("$date $time", formatter)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant().toEpochMilli()
    }
```

Index 15 is at "PM" and 09:11 is a valid AM/PM time.

Comment: What does `Locale.getDefault` return in your program? The code works fine with `en_US` locale. You may want to pass it explicitly to the [`ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) method

Comment: I'm using an Android device configured with English and it returns en_GB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has forbidden methods. You should never ever call them. If your IDE has the facility to generate warnings on any invocation of a method regardless of where it appears, add these methods to this list.

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)` **is one of them**. It is forbidden. Do not use it.

The problem is, it presumes locale from your system. In your case, it has presumed the UK locale. Let's reverse the exercise:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 16, 2, 21, 11, 0);
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a", Locale.UK)));

>02/16/21 09:11 pm

// huh.

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 16, 2, 21, 11, 0);
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)));

>02/16/21 09:11 PM
```

Well, look at that. Evidently, in british locale, AM/PM is written lowercase.

By default, DTF is **case sensitive**. That's all that's wrong here; if you try to parse with lowercase `pm` instead, it works fine. You can explicitly ask for case insensitive, but that's not the fix here. The locale might be chinese or japanese and perhaps `a` means something quite different there.

The real fix is to **never call this method**, and instead use the override where you explicitly specify the locale. That one is fine:

```
private fun extractTimestamp(date: String, time: String): Long {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)
        return LocalDateTime.parse("$date $time", formatter)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant().toEpochMilli()
    }
```

The only thing I changed is that I added `, Locale.ENGLISH` in there.

Ocassionally you are faced with the need to actually go with the platform default, for example when rendering a time to the user. I strongly suggest you *still* skip these methods, instead making it explict by using `Locale.getDefault()`. Perhaps superfluous code, but in this case there is no question: That makes your code vastly easier to read by making clear that a default is being applied. It would have most likely meant you didn't have to write up a stack overflow answer, for example. Shorter code isn't always better code.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. I usually use en_US on my devices but this en_GB configured device revealed a problem I was unlikely to catch on my own.